# Run bash with see the prints made by echo in script

Tags: linux, bash

I got one script and I am designning a new one and the given script will be used and be called.

The thing is that the given one contains lots of "echo" prints.

Is there a way to use given script but not get those prints in the console?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run this,

```
yourscript.sh > /dev/null
```

It will send the output far, far away

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `yourscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 1>/dev/null

# rest of the script...
```